# NodeJS serve_static fallthrough

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I see that serve-static will fall through to the next express .use when there is an error (in other words, it will call next()), but I can't seem to find anything that will allow it to fall through EVERY time.

My objective is to take what the serve-static builds, then have it fall through to a new module that will append a header and footer to the response.  I'm trying to do it within node due to the limitations of creating partials client-side.

tldr; how do i get serve-static to fall through every time, because it doesn't appear to do so by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at it for a while it doesn't make sense to have serve-static really anywhere but at the bottom.  All of the filters, routers, translators, and other middleware, etc... should prepend it so that the correct information is then given to serve_static to push out.

My question was based upon a lack of understanding how things such as templates work.